# Logback not able to instantiate FileAppender - Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender

Tags: java, logback, rollingfileappender, logback-classic, fileappender

I have logback setup and working in my application using the ConsoleAppender, but I want to add the FileAppender to my configuration so that I can start getting logs in a file as well. However, when I change my logback.xml file to include the FileAppender in the configuration, I get a stacktrace and an error from logback saying it couldn't instantiate the type `ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender`.

Incidentally, I was just starting out by getting FileAppender working, but just learned that RollingFileAppender is what I would need to support files that, well, roll. So I will likely ultimately be using that appender if it matters.

Here's my `logback.xml` file.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>C:\testFile.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <!-- set immediateFlush to false for much higher logging throughput -->
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
            ch.qos.logback.classic.​encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And here is the logged output in the console

```
17:56:14,729 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - This is logback-classic version 1.4.3
17:56:14,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
17:56:14,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/C:/data-sync-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/logback.xml]
17:56:14,812 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@43ee72e6 - URL [jar:file:/C:/data-sync-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
17:56:14,999 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [STDOUT]
17:56:14,999 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
17:56:15,015 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:56:15,077 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [FILE]
17:56:15,077 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender]
17:56:15,077 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Could not create an Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:69)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:44)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:33)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.handle(AppenderModelHandler.java:67)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:241)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:200)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:166)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configureByResource(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:53)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:34)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:98)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:77)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initializeLoggerContext(LogbackServiceProvider.java:50)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initialize(LogbackServiceProvider.java:41)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:152)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:139)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:422)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:408)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at      at com.domain.program.App.<clinit>(App.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:56)
        at      ... 24 common frames omitted
17:56:15,077 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@233fe9b6 - Failed to traverse model appender ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelHandlerException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelHandlerException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.handle(AppenderModelHandler.java:75)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:241)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:200)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:166)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configureByResource(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:53)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:34)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:98)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:77)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initializeLoggerContext(LogbackServiceProvider.java:50)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initialize(LogbackServiceProvider.java:41)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:152)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:139)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:422)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:408)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at      at com.domain.program.App.<clinit>(App.java:12)
Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:69)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:44)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:33)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.handle(AppenderModelHandler.java:67)
        at      ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:56)
        at      ... 24 common frames omitted
17:56:15,077 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [FILE]
17:56:15,077 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender]
17:56:15,077 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Could not create an Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:69)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:44)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:33)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.handle(AppenderModelHandler.java:67)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:241)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:200)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:166)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configureByResource(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:53)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:34)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:98)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:77)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initializeLoggerContext(LogbackServiceProvider.java:50)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initialize(LogbackServiceProvider.java:41)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:152)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:139)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:422)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:408)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at      at com.domain.program.App.<clinit>(App.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:56)
        at      ... 24 common frames omitted
17:56:15,077 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@233fe9b6 - Failed to traverse model appender ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelHandlerException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelHandlerException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.handle(AppenderModelHandler.java:75)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:241)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:200)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:166)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configureByResource(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:53)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:34)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:98)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:77)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initializeLoggerContext(LogbackServiceProvider.java:50)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initialize(LogbackServiceProvider.java:41)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:152)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:139)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:422)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:408)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at      at com.domain.program.App.<clinit>(App.java:12)
Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:69)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:44)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:33)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.handle(AppenderModelHandler.java:67)
        at      ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender
        at      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:56)
        at      ... 24 common frames omitted
17:56:15,077 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@233fe9b6 - End of configuration.
17:56:15,077 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@358ee631 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

My pom.xml dependencies section looks like this

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.SP1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

------------------------------ EDIT ------------------------------

I have tried fixing this by adding logback.core in my pom.xml, but I still get the same error. I have also confirmed that both `logback-core-1.4.3.jar` and `logback-classic-1.4.3.jar` are in my lib folder.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.l<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.?core.FileAppender`

Comment: I think you miss the `logback-core` dependency

Comment: @Jens I did try fixing it by adding logback-core to my pom.xml, but I still had the same problem.

Comment: @Jens Nevermind, this fixes it, I tried it again and it's working! Thanks for your help. If you want to add an answer I will mark it as answered. I *did* try doing this before but I think I didn't copy the deploy correctly or something. Thanks again!